# Device subcription to topic on AWS IoT

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, aws-iot

I was trying out AWS IoT with my Raspberry Pi using Node.js and aws-iot-device-sdk. It is connecting fine but on `.subscribe` it is not calling the callback function. and publish is not publishing. Please if you can point me in the right direction. I have also created a rule on AWS IoT where all data from `topic3` is republished to `topic2`.

```js
var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');

var device = awsIot.device({
    "host": "A3SXXXXXXXXXXX.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
    "port": 8883,
    "clientId": "MyClientId",
    "thingName": "MyThingName",
    "caCert": "./certs/root-CA.crt",
    "clientCert": "./certs/certificate.pem.crt",
    "privateKey": "./certs/private.pem.key"
});
device
  .on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connected');
    device.subscribe({'topic3':0}, function(error, result) {
   console.log(error);
      console.log(result);
    });
    device.publish('topic2', JSON.stringify({ test_data: 2}));
  });
```

Comment: Its alright guys, I have found what was lacking. The rule in my AWS IoT wasn't configured to republish to topic rather it was to logging. Dumb mistake to do but it happens. Now everything is fine and running well. But still am confused why the callback function on subscription is not being called. Maybe there is no callback for that. I will dig into mqtt.js documentation for that

Comment: Hi @Sandeep Randhawa.. I have 2 questions if you can help. 1). How would you run the nodeJS program in background. like for e.g. I am using node "test.js" to run the program. Now if I close the SSH session the server gets killed too. How are we supposed to run it in background. 2). How can we do a switch based on the results we get from the response.

Comment: @Ankit Khanna you can use forever or pm2 for node process management. However I would recommend using `nohup` e.g `nohup node index.js &`. And I didn't get your second question can you please elaborate what you want to achieve here.

Comment: Hi @Sandeep Randhawa - Thanks for the help. I found the same answer like forever while searching further on it. As I am new to Node JS I wasn't aware of it :) The answer to my second question is the routing that's there on the nodeJS using express. So basically I have a REST API with action parameter and based on the action I have used routing to switch the AWS IoT calls. It's working fine now :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you specify the iot:Receive action in the policy?
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/policy-actions.html

> iot:Receive
>   Represents the permission to receive a message from AWS IoT. The iot:Receive permission is checked every time a message is delivered to a client. Because this permission is checked on every delivery, it can be used to revoke permissions to clients that are currently subscribed to a topic.

I had a similar problem to what you have encountered where the subscribe callback was never invoked. My IOT client was publishing and subscribing to the same topic. Publishing works but the subscribe callback never got executed. After adding the iot:Receive action to the same topic, the subscribe callback works now as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there no policy statement for publishing and subscribing in the policy attached to the certificate of device. In order to publish and subscribe to AWS IoT brocker, the policy attached to device should contain the following statements:

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "iot:Publish",
    "iot:Subscribe",
    "iot:Connect",
    "iot:Receive"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "*"
  ]
}
```